# Looking for a graph algorithm that finds the path with minimum cost, considering multiple starting points

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

First of all I apologize if my vocabulary isn't the best. I'm not used to write in English while talking about math.

I'm currently dealing an optimization problem where I have to find the path with minimal cost of the edges between nodes (Vi, Vj) while maximizing the value of the edges which are self-loops (Vi, Vi)  (which is the main objective). I also have 4 starting points: P1, P2, P3, P4 which I have to consider simultaneously and have to find a path for all.
The edges between nodes can take any value, but the all nodes can have up to 3 self-loops and they can only have 3 values: {2,3,4}
Once again, the main idea is to maximize the values of the chosen self-loops, while minimizing the values of the other edges all while taking into account some constraints. They are:

- the amount of weight of all edges chosen combined cannot exceed a certain value X
- the path of any node Pi can't have a node that was already contained in another path there from another node Pj
- we can only choose 1 self-loop of a certain node Pi per path.

Here's a small example of a node like that: [example of node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOaYO.jpg)

And here's a small example of an application:

Let each starting point Pi be the home of a person. Each person wants to spend has much time as possible in stores(nodes) each day. But they can only spend 2, 3 or 4 hours in each store. And if any person has visited
a certain store(node), no other person can visit it.
But it takes some time to travel to each store (weight of the edge). So, my goal is to maximize the time people spend in stores while minimizing the time they spend traveling to each store, considering they can spend at max 10h per day in travels+stores.

Do any of you know any particular algorithm or theorem that may help me with this? I'm not that familiar with the "modern" graph theory as I've only learned things like Dijsktra algorithm and Trémeaux trees.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you can simplify the statement of your problem by removing the multiple loops. It is trivial that the best choice is to always take the biggest loop. This will make your question more straightforward to anyone reading it.

Comment: The problem  is a bit unclear. Do you need to find paths starting from each $P_i$ and ending anywhere, or should the paths end at a specific location?

Comment: Also, in your example, there is as much $V$ vertices than $P$ vertices, is it always the case ?

Comment: I think I didn't make myself very clear. I'll try to rephrase with an example.
Let each starting point Pi be the home of a person. Each person wants to spend has much time as possible in stores(nodes) each day. But they can only spend 2, 3 or 4 hours in each store. And if any person has visited Store(node) 1, no other person can visit it.
But it takes some time to travel to each store (weight of the edge). So, my goal is to maximize the time people spend in stores while minimizing the time they spend traveling to each store, considering they can spend at max 10h per day in travels+stores.

Comment: Each Pi must end on a node V. And there are way more V vertices than P ones.

Comment: Oh, ok, the max condition is on weights on both edges and self-loops, so multiple loops are not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

In the case where you only have one starting point and no threshold condition (or a very flexible one), the problem is equivalent to the longest path problem, which is NP-hard, so there is no polynomial algorithm for this problem (unless P=NP).
In practice, to solve your problem, you might need to model the problem, as a mixed-integer linear program for example, and solve it using a MILP solver.
You can also look at the literature about vehicle routing, your problem shares common points. This is also pretty close to k-path cover, or [path cover with bounded length](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67403/path-cover-with-paths-of-bounded-length-in-the-plane), there is a bit of literature on it. This also shares similarities with [shortest paths with knapsack constraint](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319649788_Optimal_paths_of_knapsack-set_vertices_on_a_weight-independent_graph). I'm not sure all of it will be useful, but this can give you inspiration on efficient heuristics, or on how to model it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll look them up. Do you by chance know of any algorithm or method that considers more than one starting point?

Comment: The multiple depots vehicule routing problem is the generalization of VRP with multiple starting points.